# Scroll lateral en Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, scroll

Tengo un problema, en ciertas páginas me aparece un scroll horizontal que no logro arreglar ni comprender...
https://metalsystem.site/mesas-elevadoras/extraplanas/
Alguien me podría ayudar por favor...!?

Comment: Hasta donde he podido investigar, el problema viene en los submenus de productos y/o empresa (y me ha parecido que en el menu soluciones tambien pasa algo raro), repasad como están creados pues si los quitais vereis que funciona bien.  Esto es un problema que no se puede reproducir aquí y dudo que esta pregunta no sea cerrada pronto, lo siento, saludos!

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo, @PedroPicateclas ha solventado el error.

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro, veo que no iba tan desencaminado, el problema estaba en los submenus como decia, pero cuando lo estuve mirando vi tanto follon de clases que se entremezclaban que no me vi capaz. @PedroPicateclas desde luego ha tenido que esforzarse un buen rato para darte esa solución, sin duda. Le debes una y gorda :-)

Comment: La verdad que si y no se si puedo "premiar" de alguna manera a vosotros por haber respondido tan bien y pronto. 

Por otra parte veo ahora que se ha arreglado el scroll lateral pero apareció espacio en blanco debajo del footer que antes no aparecía... tengo una patata caliente con esta web que no hay manera...!! Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por si te sirve de ayuda, añadiendo lo siguiente al selector se soluciona:

```
.elementor-10 
.elementor-element.elementor-element-f56c695 
.elementskit-navbar-nav-default 
.elementskit-dropdown {
      max-width: 100%;
}
```

Esto es provocado por el submenú productos.

Un saludo

Comment: mil gracias por tu respuesta, la verdad que funciona prefectamente bien.

Comment: Me ha sido de gran ayuda tu respuesta, agradecer tu tiempo!